# Detect if content of EditText was changed by user or programmatically?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, textwatcher

I would need a way to detect if the EditText has been changed by the user typing something or by the app changing the text programmatically. Any standard way of doing this? I guess I could always do something hackish like unsetting the TextWatcher before `setText()` and setting it back again afterwards, but there's got to be a better way of doing this... right?

I tried checking if the EditText is focused in the TextWatcher, but that was of little help since the EditTexts gets focused "semi-randomly" anyway when scrolling...

**Background**

I have a ListView with EditTexts in every listitem. I've sorted out the basic problem of storing the values for the EditTexts for reuse when the user scrolls.

I also have a TextWatcher that sums up the values in all EditTexts and displays the sum when the user edits the content of any of the EditTexts.

The problem is that when I'm scrolling the list and my custom adapter is reentering the stored values in the EditTexts on `bindView()`, that also triggers the TextWatchers `afterTextChanged()` method, causing the scrolling to lag because the summing-up-function is triggered.

Comment: you can override OnKeyDown() and inside that trigger a boolean so you know that the user is entering text and use that inside your textwatcher

Comment: @JRowan Yeah I thought of ditching the TextWatcher and relying on onKeyDown() instead, but according to the documentation _"Key presses in software keyboards will generally NOT trigger this listener, although some may elect to do so in some situations. **Do not rely on this to catch software key presses**."_ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)

Comment: @BadCash how many TextWatchers do you have?

Comment: How about setting a class variable flag when you are adjusting it in code, and in your text watcher, check that flag, and then reset it?

Comment: @pskink One per item in the listview, they're instantiated in the newItem() method.

Comment: I had some success clearing the focus when the view is being bound.  Then only react to text edits if the `EditText` actually has focus.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This sorted itself out a long time ago, but for anyone who finds their way here looking for an answer, here's what I did:

I ended up setting the Tag of the EditText to some arbitrary value right before I'm about to change it programmatically, and changing the value, and then resetting the Tag to null. Then in my TextWatcher.afterTextChanged() method I check if the Tag is null or not to determine if it was the user or the program that changed the value. Works like a charm!

Something like this:

```
edit.setTag( "arbitrary value" );
edit.setText( "My Text Value" );
edit.setTag(null);
```

and then

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if( view.getTag() == null )             
        // Value changed by user
    else
        // Value changed by program
}
```

Comment: worked for me! thank you for the easy and simple solution

Comment: This solution is amazing. This solved a struggle we've been having for over a year. The one catch is that you shouldn't check the editText's tag inside of coroutine block - be sure to set a variable outside the block and then check it inside.

Comment: Whats view.getTag() getting error there!?

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is perfectly valid, but I have another approach;

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, 
                         int start, int before, int count) {
    boolean userChange = Math.abs(count - before) == 1; 
    if (userChange) { 

    }
}
```

It works by checking if the change was a single character.
This is not a fool-proof solution as copy-paste operations might be missed, and non-user changes of a single character will also be missed.
Depending on your use case, this might be a viable solution.

Comment: Best solution... easy to understand

Comment: So what happens when the user pastes something in the `EditText`? ;)

Comment: So what happens when the user taps on an auto suggested word?

Comment: Wrong answer. Will produce wrong results if using any cut/paste or highlighting edits. Simply wrong.

Comment: This is wrong answer because of following reasons
1. User pastes something in as suggested by @reVerse
2. User taps on some suggestion by Aloha
Not sure why so many people has upvoted this :(

Comment: What if you programmatically change one character? Not a good solution.

Comment: The user can also paste text with more than 1 char!

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your use case (e.g. you are auto-populating this field when the user types into another field), you can also check if the view has focus, e.g.:

```
textView.doAfterTextChanged {
    val isValueChangedByUser = textView.hasFocus()
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing that helped to me is having boolean canListenInput field. Use it inside of watcher.

```
    email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (canListenInput) {
                emailChanged = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Clear it before changing text programmatically. Set it inside of onAttachedToWindow, (after state) restoration:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    canListenInput = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created some extension methods to tackle this scenario

```kotlin
inline fun TextView.runTaggingCode(block: () -> Unit) {
    this.setTag(R.string.tag_text_id, "set_from_code")
    block()
    this.setTag(R.string.tag_text_id, null)
}

fun TextView.isTaggedForCode() = this.getTag(R.string.tag_text_id) != null
```

where I have defined the `R.string.tag_text_id` as below

```xml
<string name="tag_text_id" translatable="false">dummy</string>
```

Now where I to use these methods, I will simply change my code as below,

```kotlin
override fun beforeTextChanged(
    s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int,
    after: Int,
) {
    if (textView.isTaggedForCode()) {
        return
    }
    textView.runTaggingCode { 
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

But in case you don't want to change the same text view text, in it own `TextWatcher` you can also see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65130528/5028085)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by adding:

```
private String current = "";
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
if(!s.toString().equals(current)){
   [your_edittext].removeTextChangedListener(this);

   //Format your string here...

   current = formatted;
   [your_edittext].setText(formatted);
   [your_edittext].setSelection(formatted.length());

   [your_edittext].addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```